# M2Eclipse complains about the lifecycle with I use 'javac-with-errorprone' as the compiler

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, errorprone

My team has recently decided to use `javac-with-errorprone`, and Eclipse complains about not being able to map it to the lifecycle. How can I resolve this without telling Eclipse to ignore it as is the "normal" way to deal with missing m2e connectors?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerId>javac-with-errorprone</compilerId>
        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in the default life cycle mapping for the maven-compiler-plugin it looks for [compilerId being "`javac`"](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/fdff39e0396a4c8501ef8c2cddbaaf73c8069990/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml#L22), so when you change it to "`javac-with-errorprone`" it suddenly doesn't know what to do.

The solution is to make a lifecycle mapping, but instead of the usual thing (ignoring the goals), [use the same configurator as the mapper did before](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core/blob/fdff39e0396a4c8501ef8c2cddbaaf73c8069990/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml#L27) (`org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.javaConfigurator`).

**Unfortunately this does not give you error highlighting** as Eclipse is still using its special compiler. However, you can rest assured knowing you aren't ignoring the compiler plugin in Eclipse.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.3,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <configurator>
                                        <id>org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.javaConfigurator</id>
                                    </configurator>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```